# Strange behavior with datetime fields in Odoo domain

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using `saas-14`. My database contains a `purchase.order.line` with an `id = 98` and `create_date = 2018-04-07 01:04:32`. The create date for this object is the most recent create date for any `purchase.order.line` in the system. In other words, there are no other `purchase.order.line` objects in the system where `create_date > 2018-04-07 01:04:32`.

I have the following code in an server action for a `purchase.order.line`:

```
raise Warning(env['purchase.order.line'].search([('create_date', '>', record.create_date)]).id)
```

When I trigger this action for the existing `purchase.order.line(98,)`, the result is `98`. In other words, the system seems to think that `2018-04-07 01:04:32 > 2018-04-07 01:04:32`. That obviously doesn't make any sense.

I would expect the action to return `false`. Why is this happening?